# @include not being detected and media breakpoints are not working?

Tags: html, css, sass, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm for this project, and I'm trying to do a thing where when the resolution gets to `596px` or below, the footer of the page is not displayed.

When using `@include` I get an error saying "Unknown at rule" and the breakpoint does nothing.

I have imported my footer.css file after bootstrap in my HTML page so everything is loaded properly.

**Footer:**

```
<div class="footer">
    <p style="margin-top: 15px">Track Transport</p>
</div>
```

**Breakpoint being used with the @include error:**

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    .footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I tried also using an "`!important`" on the CSS but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You should tag your question with 'phpstorm'.

Comment: Where do you use that `@include` (what file)? Is it `footer.css`? AFAIK it has to be .saas/.scss/.less/etc file that will be **transpiled** into the actual CSS later

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. I had no knowledge of that... Thank you sir.